# Convert vec3b into mat

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I have color image in `im`, i want to get the pixel value of 3 channels image using vec3b using the following code

```
    for (int i = 0; i < im.rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < im.cols; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < nChannels; k++)
        {
            zay[k] = im.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[k]; //get the pixel value and assign to new vec3b variable zay


        }

    }

}
```

After that, i want to multiply the following mat 3x3 filter with that vec3b in zay

```
    Filter= (Mat_<double>(3, 3) << 0, 0, 0,
                                0, 1, 0,
                                0, 0, 0);
```

How to convert vec3b into mat matrix so i can multiplied with mat Filter?? And vec3b is an array 3x1?
Thanks

Comment: I guess manual computation will be easier and faster (maybe in macro/function): Vec3b temp; temp[0] = zay[0] * Filter.at<double>(0,0) + ...

Comment: But i want to convert to mat because i need flexible matrix. So i can operate a*b and b*a easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didnt try but should work:

```
cv::Mat DoubleMatFromVec3b(cv::Vec3b in)
{
    cv::Mat mat(3,1, CV_64FC1);
    mat.at <double>(0,0) = in [0];
    mat.at <double>(1,0) = in [1];
    mat.at <double>(2,0) = in [2];

    return mat;
};
```

Comment: I liked it. Clean and simple, +1.

Answer (score 3):

According to your example, what you are trying to accomplish is known as a **convolution with a kernel**.

You can set up the kernel and invoke [`cv::filter2D()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#void%20filter2D(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20ddepth,%20InputArray%20kernel,%20Point%20anchor,%20double%20delta,%20int%20borderType)) to apply it for you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("input.jpg");
    if (img.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "!!! Failed to open input image" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cv::Mat kernel = (cv::Mat_<float>(3, 3) << 0, 0, 0,
                                               0, 1, 0,
                                               0, 0, 0);

    cv::Mat dst;
    cv::filter2D(img, dst, -1, kernel, cv::Point(-1, -1), 0, cv::BORDER_DEFAULT);

    cv::imshow("output", dst);
    cv::waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Thus, there's no need to iterate on the pixels and perform the computation yourself.
OpenCV documentation explains it all at: [Making your own linear filters!](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/filter_2d/filter_2d.html).