# Assign 3x1 mat to 3 channels mat

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

This question is continuance from my question in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27676352/convert-vec3b-into-mat/27676855#27676855).  After i get mat matrix, the 3x1 matrix is multiplied with 3x3 mat matrix.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < im.rows; i++)
    {
    for (int j = 0; j < im.cols; j++)
        {
        for (int k = 0; k < nChannels; k++)
           {
            zay(k) = im.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[k]; // get pixel value and assigned to Vec4b zay

            }
        //convert to mat, so i can easily multiplied it
        mat.at <double>(0, 0) = zay[0];
        mat.at <double>(1, 0) = zay[1];
        mat.at <double>(2, 0) = zay[2];
```

We get 3x1 mat matrix and do multiplication with the filter.

```
        multiply= Filter*mat;
```

And i get mat matrix 3x1. I want to assign the value into my new 3 channels mat matrix, how to do that? I want to construct an images using this operation. I'm not use convolution function, because i think the result is different. I'm working in c++, and i want to change the coloured images to another color using matrix multiplication. I get the algorithm from this [paper](http://biecoll.ub.uni-bielefeld.de/volltexte/2007/52/pdf/ICVS2007-6.pdf). In that paper, we need to multiplied several matrix to get the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV gives you a reshape function to change the number of channels/rows/columns implicitly:

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-reshape

This is very efficient since no data is copied, only the matrix header is changed.

try:

```
cv::Mat mat3Channels = mat.reshape(3,1);
```

Didn't test it, but should work. It should give you a 1x1 matrix with 3 channel element (Vec3d) if you want a `Vec3b` element instead, you have to convert it:

```
cv::Mat mat3ChannelsVec3b;
mat3Channels.convertTo(mat3ChannelsVec3b, CV_8UC3);
```

If you just want to write your `mat` back, it might be better to create a single `Vec3b` element instead:

```
cv::Vec3b element3Channels;
element3Channels[0] = multiply.at<double>(0,0);
element3Channels[1] = multiply.at<double>(1,0);
element3Channels[2] = multiply.at<double>(2,0);
```

But care in all cases, that Vec3b elements can't save values `< 0` and `> 255`

Edit: After reading your question again, you ask how to assign...

I guess you have another matrix:

```
cv::Mat outputMatrix = cv::Mat(im.rows, im.cols, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(0,0,0));
```

Now to assign `multiply` to the element in `outputMatrix` you ca do:

```
cv::Vec3b element3Channels;
element3Channels[0] = multiply.at<double>(0,0);
element3Channels[1] = multiply.at<double>(1,0);
element3Channels[2] = multiply.at<double>(2,0);
outputMatrix.at<Vec3b>(i, j) = element3Channels;
```

If you need alpha channel too, you can adapt that easily.

Comment: Thank you. In OpenCV, the format of coloured image is BGR right? If i want to manipulate the images using matrix multiplication, should i change the order of the colour to RGB? Or BGR is same with RGB? Because i usually use MatLab to do this, we know if MatLab have RGB in their coloured image format.

Comment: You can convert to RGB ordering easily. OpenCV uses BGR ordering if not converted and assumes BGR ordering for displaying and writing to disk. So if you convert to RGB before processing you should convert back to BGR after processing.